# Maven's set version plugin doesn't set parent version in child module

Tags: java, maven, maven-versions-plugin

While I was trying to automate the version updates of all the poms in the project, I couldn't fix this issue. The versions:set plugin/command does replace almost every version of a pom but not the versions of the parent pom (another project) defined in the parent part of the pom.xml itself.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>3.19.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<groupId>com.test.app.child</groupId>
<version>3.21.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<artifactId>helloWorldChild</artifactId>
<name>${project.groupId}::${project.artifactId}</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

As you can see the two versions are different. This is after I executed the following command:

```
mvn versions:set -DgroupId=com.test.app.* -DartifactId=* -DoldVersion=* -DnewVersion=3.21.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The expected result is, that both, an all versions versions are **3.21.0-SNAPSHOT** instead of 3.19.0-SNAPSHOT. Is there any possibility to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your version and group should come from the parent, they should not be set in the child, only the artifact should be set in the child.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>3.19.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<artifactId>helloWorldChild</artifactId>
<name>${project.groupId}::${project.artifactId}</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Comment: Unfortunately our project doesn't allow this for several reasons. Still any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: they're the rules of maven, you are breaking them, this is the way multi module projects work